# Find middle node of linked list

Tags: c++

I ran this function on a linked list with elements `1 2 3 4 5` in that order. When I print the data member of the returned node my output is `2`. Why is the output `2`? When I put the line `two = two->next` in the `if` scope though I get `3`. I don't understand why I'm getting `2` the way it is written.

```
SLNode* mid(SLNode *head) {
    SLNode *one = head;
    SLNode *two = head;
    while(one != nullptr) {
        one = one->next;
        two = two->next;
        if(one != nullptr) {
            one = one->next;
            //two = two->next;
        }
    }
    return two;
}
```

EDIT::

So I guess the list was actually `5 4 3 2 1` and it was going that extra one node since there are odd number of elements. Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Well **one** is a pointer to the start of the list **head**. **two** also points to the start of the list. You are then basically only advancing **two** and returning it, which is the 2nd element.